# How to enter series of points along certain angle at regular distances in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, utm, bearing

I would like to enter a series of points along a certain angle in ArcMap.  I have a UTM coordinate as a starting point, and from that I'd like to enter 10 points at a 120 degree bearing every 50 meters. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

From the context menu while digitizing a new line I would use [**Absolute X,Y**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m70000006m000000) to enter the coordinates of the start vertex and **[Direction/Length](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m700000047000000)** to do the second (and last) vertex 120 degrees and 500 metres away.

You then have a selected line which is ready for **[Construct Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m60000000n000000)** which "creates new point features at intervals along a selected line".

Answer (score 0):

perhaps draw the line using the create features tool. right click for angle/bearing (can't remember) and put 120 degrees. Then right click and hit length, enter 50 meters. This will lock your draw feature tool into a 50 meter line at 120 degrees. continue this 10 more times then use Data Management > Features > Feature Vertices to Points.

There is probably a better way but this should work

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a simple trigonometry task, perhaps excel is the easiest approach. You should be able to set up a simple recursive spreadsheet using the equations below.

Assuming your 0 degree line coincides with the positive direction on the y axis then:

x1 = x + 25

y1 = y + 25*sqrt(3)

Where (x,y) is the coordinates of your starting point and (x1,y1) give you the first point. Now just repeat 49 more times :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Direction-Distance* tool from the Editor toolbar:

[image]

The tool creates a point using a distance from a known point plus a direction from a known point to define a bearing line.

A step by step instruction can be found in [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m700000053000000).